# Facebook Get User Wall Feed Posts iOS Android

Tags: android, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk

I try to implement iOS and Android apps with ability to get and show user Facebook account feed posts (his own posts on wall).

I have tried https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN and graph.facebook.com/me/posts?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN
but it returns empty data in browser and in app:

```
{
   "data": [

   ]
}
```

I tried to make some posts on user wall with Public permission, but it doesn't make sense.

Graph API for that call doesn't helped me much.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/user/feed

I need to get user posts for certain time interval with text and images (if exist) in this posts.
Is it in any case requires "read_stream" permission? If so, how get it?

Is there any working solution or any tutorial?

Comment: Have you tried to follow the following documentation for requesting permissions here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios/v2.3 . Please reference the "Get Permissions" section. Also are you able to get the posts for your API call when using the Graph Explorer? https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/

Comment: Big thanks! Finally I found the answer. I will make detailed post with answer later.